# Почему переопределения метода не происходит?

Tags: c#-8.0

```cs
public interface INTFileStore
{
    NTStatus CreateFile(...);
}

public class NTDirectoryFileSystem : INTFileStore
{
    public NTStatus CreateFile(...)
    {
        // code...
    }
}

public class TrashDirectoryFileSystem : NTDirectoryFileSystem
{
    public new NTStatus CreateFile(...)
    {
        // code...
    }
}
```

По какой причине переопределения метода не происходит?
Хотя `new` стоит, а `rider` и компилятор так не считают.
Однако если наследовать и класс и интерфейс, тогда все работает нормально.

```cs
public class TrashDirectoryFileSystem : NTDirectoryFileSystem, INTFileStore // вот так работает
{
    public new NTStatus CreateFile(...)
    {
        // code...
    }
}
```

Почему так странно работают переопределение, если есть `interface`?